# Item number not aligned with tasks

Tags: enumerate, line-numbering, tasks

I have an alignment issue when using enumerate and tasks. Specifically, when  I have a "blank" item with associated tasks, the item # and task # don't line up horizontally. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
   \item Some item % Looks ok here
   \begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[a]),item-indent=0em, label-offset=1.00em, ](2)%
      \task Task a
      \task Task b
      \task Task c
      \task Task d
   \end{tasks}
   \item % With no "item", the item # and task #s don't line up horizontally
   \begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[a]),item-indent=0em, label-offset=1.00em, ](2)%
      \task Task a
      \task Task b
      \task Task c
      \task Task d
   \end{tasks}
   \item Another item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work-around:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
   \item Some item % Looks ok here
   \begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[a]),item-indent=0em, label-offset=1.00em, ](2)%
      \task Task a
      \task Task b
      \task Task c
      \task Task d
   \end{tasks}
   \item \leavevmode\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep}%
   \begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[a]),item-indent=0em, label-offset=1.00em](2)%
      \task Task a
      \task Task b
      \task Task c
      \task Task d
   \end{tasks}
   \item Another item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This fix doesn't seem to work anymore, could you update your answer @Bernard?